# Why to specify a pointer type?

Tags: c++, c, pointers

What actually happens while declaring a pointer of a specific type? Is there any use to specify a type to a pointer other than pointer Arithmetic or Indexing?

Comment: Without the type, how do you know to what the pointer points?

Comment: How would you write data to a memory location through pointer without knowing the type of the data that location is allocated for?

Comment: Related or Duplicate: [What are the differences between a pointer variable and a reference variable in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/57483/514235)

Comment: You can specify that a pointer points to an object of an unknown type: `void* ptr;` Try to use it throughout a program and tell us how far have you got.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Type of a pointer is needed in following situations

- Dereferencing the pointer
- Pointer arithmetic

Here is the example of dereferencing the pointer.

```
{
    char *ptr; //pointer of type char
    short j=256;
    ptr=&j;    // Obviously You have to ignore the warnings
    printf("%d",*ptr)
}
```

Now because `ptr` is of type char so it will only read one byte. But the binary value of 256 is `0000000100000000` but because `ptr` is of type `char` so it will read only first byte hence the output will be `0`.

Note: if we assign j=127 then output will be 127 because 127 will be hold by first byte.

Now, the example of `pointer arithmetic`:

```
{
    int *ptr;
    int var=0;
    ptr=&var;
    var++;
    ptr++;// pointer arithmetic
}
```

Are statements `var++` and `ptr++` are same thing? No, `var++` means `var=var+1` and `ptr++` means `ptr=ptr+4`. Because the compiler "knows" this is a pointer and that it points to an `int`, it adds `4` to `ptr` instead of 1, so the pointer "points to" the next integer.

Comment: I don't think this is correct because you can declare a pointer to an incomplete type i.e. you can declare a pointer to a class that you have declared but not defined. The compiler has no idea how big the class is, but it still allows you to declare a pointer to it.

Answer (score 11):

One of the reasons could be that when you dereference the pointer we should know how many bytes to read right? Dereferencing `char` pointer would imply taking one byte from memory while for `int` it could be 4 bytes.

Comment: That's all? I thought the answer is "because you have to" - `auto x = *ptr;`, `func(*ptr);`...

Comment: @LogicStuff Sorry not sure I am following you. If you feel something lacks, please consider adding another answer. I also answered this question mainly from C point of view, since the question was also tagged like that.

Comment: Oh, Ok then. I was simply saying what the first comment under the question is saying.

Comment: I don't think this is correct because you can declare a pointer to an incomplete type i.e. you can declare a pointer to a class that you have declared but not defined. The compiler has no idea how big the class is, but it still allows you to declare a pointer to it.

Answer (score 2):

- **Size**: How many bytes do you access? Reading/writing a `char` of 1 byte isn't the same as writing a `long` of ≥ 4 octets.
- **Alignment**: Two types might be the same length but have different alignment. One data type might be put into a special register and memory moves from/to these register have special alignment requirements.
- **Representation**: Even with same `sizeof` and `_Alignof`, the representation might differ. If you assign a `*float_ptr = 4`, the `4` gets converted to `4.0`.
- **Type safety**: Gross misconduct like `void **ptr1, **ptr2; *ptr1+*ptr2;` can be detected.

Answer (score 1):

A pointer is a variable whose value is the address of another variable

Here are few examples for pointer types:

```
int    *ip;    /* pointer to an integer */

double *dp;    /* pointer to a double */

float  *fp;    /* pointer to a float */

char   *ch     /* pointer to a character */
```

The actual data type of the value of all pointers, whether integer, float, character, or otherwise, is the same, a long hexadecimal number that represents a memory address.

The only difference between pointers of different data types is the data type of the variable or constant that the pointer points to

Comment: This is all good for definition. I guess the question is more about usage of pointer, that is what you gain upon knowing the data type also?

Comment: "The actual data type of the value of all pointers, ... is the same".  That's not (necessarily) true.  Word addressed machines can use one data type for the address of a word (which typically covers integer, float, and struct pointers), and a *different* data type for the address of a word + the offset within a word (which covers char pointers and void pointers).  Segmented architectures often use a different type for "pointer to function", and finally there is all the fun and games of "pointer to member" / "pointer to member functions" - which are completely different beasts.

Answer (score 0):

The Data type is needed when dereferencing the pointer so it knows how much data it should read.

For example: dereferencing a char pointer should read the next byte from the address it is pointing to, while an int pointer should read two bytes.

Refer this for more: [Why is it necessary to declare the types that pointers point to?](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-it-necessary-to-declare-the-types-that-pointers-point-to)

Answer (score 0):

Pointer also point to valid object of a class. In absence of type one cannot get information to access the members of the class.

```
class CPerson
{
    public:
        std::string GetName();
};

CPerson oPerson;
CPerson *pObj_1 = &oPerson;
pObj_1->GetName();

void *pObj_2 = &oPerson;
pObj_2-> ??  // what all I can access now ?
```